# XCode: Use hosting projects preprocessor macros in framework

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, static-libraries, preprocessor-directive

I am developing a static iOS library (that is compiled into a `.a` file). In the librarys code, I sometimes check if the framework is running in debug mode, as so:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    return YES;
#else
    return NO;
#endif
```

The issue is, that when the framework is used in a "host" project, the outcome of the above code will depend on whether the *framework* was compiled in debug or release mode (and is therefore static). What I want to do is make that outcome depend on whether the *hosting project* is currently running in debug or release configuration, so that developers using my library can enable/disable debug features on the fly.

I suppose this cannot be achieved using preprocessor macros, as they are... well... preprocessed. But is there any other high-level solution to detect the current run configuration?

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution?

Comment: Not really. I ended up offering an "enableDebug" method in the public header of my framework, so that the host project can set debug mode this way.

Comment: That's too bad, thanks!